# Processing large arrays in PowerShell

Tags: arrays, powershell, powershell-jobs

I am having a difficult time understanding the most efficient to process large datasets/arrays in PowerShell. I have arrays that have several million items that I need to process and group. This list is always different in size meaning it could be 3.5 million items or 10 million items.

Example: 3.5 million items they group by "4's" like the following:

Items 0,1,2,3 Group together 4,5,6,7 Group Together and so on.

I have tried processing the array using a single thread by looping through the list and assigning to a pscustomobject which works it just takes 45-50+ minutes to complete.

I have also attempted to break up the array into smaller arrays but that causes the process to run even longer.

```bsh
$i=0
$d_array = @()
$item_array # Large dataset


While ($i -lt $item_array.length){

    $o = "Test"
    $oo = "Test"
    $n = $item_array[$i];$i++
    $id = $item_array[$i];$i++
    $ir = $item_array[$i];$i++
    $cs = $item_array[$i];$i++

    $items = [PSCustomObject]@{
        'field1' = $o
        'field2' = $oo
        'field3' = $n
        'field4' = $id
        'field5' = $ir
        'field6'= $cs
    }
    $d_array += $items

}
```

I would imagine if I applied a job scheduler that would allow me to run the multiple jobs would cut the process time down by a significant amount, but I wanted to get others takes on a quick effective way to tackle this.

Comment: First thing you should try is to not use array addition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are working with large data, using C# is also effective.

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static class Test
{
    public static List<object> Convert(object[] src)
    {
        var result = new List<object>();
        for(var i = 0; i <= src.Length - 4; i+=4)
        {
            result.Add( new {
                field1 = "Test",
                field2 = "Test",
                field3 = src[i + 0],
                field4 = src[i + 1],
                field5 = src[i + 2],
                field6 = src[i + 3]
            });
        }
        return result;
    }
}
"@

$item_array = 1..10000000
$result = [Test]::Convert($item_array)
```

Comment: I was about to suggest exactly the change you just made yourself, by far the fastest version (+1).

Comment: Everyone here is amazing thank you for your response.

Comment: 29 ms with my example.  Nice.

Comment: Does this implementation only work on Windows or can it be used on a Mac? I am asking as I am trying to support both.

Answer (score 4):

While [rokumaru](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56408828/6811411)s version is unsurpassed, here my try with my local measurements from [js2010](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56407342/6811411)

Same `$item_array = 1..100000` applied to all versions

```
> .\SO_56406847.ps1
measuring...BDups
measuring...LotPings
measuring...Theo
measuring...js2010
measuring...rokumaru
BDups    = 75,9949897 TotalSeconds
LotPings = 2,3663763 TotalSeconds
Theo     = 2,4469917 TotalSeconds
js2010   = 2,9198114 TotalSeconds
rokumaru = 0,0109287 TotalSeconds
```

---

```
## Q:\Test\2019\06\01\SO_56406847.ps1
$i=0
$item_array = 1..100000  # Large dataset

'measuring...LotPings'
$LotPings = measure-command {
    $d_array = for($i=0;$i -lt $item_array.length;$i+=4){
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            'field1' = "Test"
            'field2' = "Test"
            'field3' = $item_array[$i]
            'field4' = $item_array[$i+1]
            'field5' = $item_array[$i+2]
            'field6' = $item_array[$i+3]
        }
    }
} # measure-command
```

Comment: That's cool, but the comma in totalseconds should be a decimal point, right?

Answer (score 2):

How's this?  32.5x faster.  Making arrays with += kills puppies.  It copies the whole array every time.

```
$i=0
$item_array = 1..100000 # Large dataset

'measuring...'

# original 1 min 5 sec                                                                 
# mine 2 sec              
# other answer, 2 or 3 sec
# c# version 0.029 sec, 2241x faster!

measure-command {

$d_array = 
While ($i -lt $item_array.length){
    $o = "Test"
    $oo = "Test"
    $n = $item_array[$i];$i++                                                      
    $id = $item_array[$i];$i++                                                     
    $ir = $item_array[$i];$i++                                                     
    $cs = $item_array[$i];$i++      
    # $items =                                               
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'field1' = $o
        'field2' = $oo
        'field3' = $n
        'field4' = $id
        'field5' = $ir
        'field6'= $cs
    }
    # $d_array += $items
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could optimize this somewhat using an [ArrayList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=netframework-4.8), or perhaps even better by using a strongly typed [List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8) but going through millions of elements in an array will still take time..

As for your code: there is no need to capture the array item values in a variable first and use that later to add to the PSCustomObject.

```
$item_array = 'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h' # Large dataset
$result = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[PSCustomObject]
# or use an ArrayList: $result = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

$i = 0
While ($i -lt $item_array.Count) {
    [void]$result.Add(
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            'field1' = "Test" # $o
            'field2' = "Test" # $oo
            'field3' = $item_array[$i++]  #$n
            'field4' = $item_array[$i++]  #$id
            'field5' = $item_array[$i++]  #$ir
            'field6' = $item_array[$i++]  #$cs
        }
    )
}

# save to a CSV file maybe ?
$result | Export-Csv 'D:\blah.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

If you need the result to become a 'normal' array again, use `$result.ToArray()`

Comment: Except in the case of maintaining compatibility with existing code, I don't think there's really a reason to even consider using `ArrayList` any more.  The `ArrayList` documentation you linked to states as such: "We don't recommend that you use the `ArrayList` class for new development. Instead, we recommend that you use the generic `List<T>` class."  Perhaps the difference between the two is not so apparent when using PowerShell as it would be with, say, a compiled language like C#, but I still think it'd be good to not present an obsolete class as a viable alternative.

Comment: @BACON AFAIK the Arraylist is not yet classified `obsolete`. It is **recommended** to not use it anymore as there is a better alternative with `List`. That is exactly the reason why I used `List` in my code and added the links to both classes in the first line of my answer.

Comment: While `ArrayList` has not been marked `[Obsolete()]` it is obsolete in that there is a newer, better alternative that should be used going forward.  The very first thing your answer mentions is `ArrayList` and then says "perhaps" `List[T]` would be better.  My point is, `List[T]` was introduced with .NET 2.0 in 2005; why even mention `ArrayList` _at all_ for non-legacy code in 2019?  Just my opinion, but including commented out code and a documentation link for `ArrayList`, which Microsoft recommends not to use, presents it as a reasonable, equivalent alternative for modern code when it's not.