# How can I speed up the counting of matching entries between two large arrays in Powershell?

Tags: arrays, powershell, collections, active-directory, powershell-5.1

I am trying to count the number of matching elements between two large Powershell arrays/collections generated by capturing Active Directory ("AD") data.
However, it is very slow.

## Concept

Note:  feel free to skip ahead to the **Application** section.

*Current concept*

I am looking to count the number of matching instances of

- all elements of a subset of array A (all elements of A are unique, and ordered)
- any element of array B (may contain duplicates).

Suppose array A contains [-30, -2, 1, 3, 4, 6, 20, 50] and the subset of interest is all positive numbers, and array B contains [50, 6, 80, 10, -2, 30, 6, 6, 50].  Then the correct count would be 2 (6 & 50 appear in both arrays; -2 is ignored).

**Note that in the real implementation** (see below)**:**

- **A and B both contain strings** (not numbers)**, and are large; and**
- **A and B may be arrays, or they may be `Collections` of user objects produced by `Get-ADUser`.**

*Alternative concept*

Alternatively, I could easily create a new array a = [1, 3, 4, 6, 20, 50] comprising the subset of A of interest and extract an ordered list of unique entries from B to form b = [-2, 6, 10, 30, 50, 80].
Then I just need to add up the number of elements appearing in both a and b (correct answer is still 2).

*Basic description of algorithm*

Array A has roughly 450,000 string elements, of which roughly 400,000 are of interest.
Array B has roughly 20,000 string elements, comprising roughly 19,000 unique values.
Currently I iterate through all elements of array A, I use `if` to check whether the element is in the subset of interest, and, if so, then I test whether the element appears in array B using the [`-contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-arrays?view=powershell-7.3#operators) operator.

*Problem with algorithm*

This takes over an hour to run.

*Possibilities to speed up algorithm*

I wondered whether it would be faster to iterate through unique elements of array B (in other words, the elements of array b), and test whether they appear in array A (or perhaps array a).  But I haven't tried it, because logically it seems as though it should take roughly the same amount of time.

Alternatively, rather than using basic arrays, is there some cleverer object like an `OrderedList` class that would be faster to search?

If there's no `OrderedList` data type, then would it be practical to split the data into subarrays myself?  For example, I could split array b into beta_1 =  [-2, 6, 10] and beta_2 =  [30, 50, 80].  Thus, if the selected element of array A has a value less than 20 I will look for it in array beta_1, and otherwise in array beta_2.
In the real problem I'm dealing with strings, and arrays with thousands of elements, so perhaps one subarray per initial (capitalised) letter of the alphabet (beta_A, beta_B, beta_C, ..., beta_Z) would be apt.  I wouldn't want to have to hard code a switch statement to choose one of 26 subarrays, so — if necessary — I'd rather index into a collection of arrays:  beta[0] rather than beta_A, through to beta[25] rather than beta_Z.  And I would anticipate using the code value of each capital letter to select the appropriate one.

## Application

*Scenario*

Some people are recorded in AD in *both* of the organisational units: `Permanent` *and* `Visitors`.  But with different details recorded in each OU (so I cannot match on telephone, address, email, *etc*.). Nevertheless, as each pair of such records relate to a single individual person, it should be reasonably informative to match on full name.  (In reality a small fraction may change their name, or provide a different version of their name.)  Full name is stored in the `Description` attribute (aside from a scattering of data entry errors).

The ultimate intention is to calculate statistics on such multiple records that exist for certain individuals.

Example:

- `$visitors.Description` = [Daniel Dingo, Betty Butternut, Adam Aardvark, Betty Butternut, Cathy Cabbage, Enid Endive]
- `$permanents.Description` = [Enid, Enid Endive, Betty Butternut, Cathy Cabbage, Fred Flamingo, Cathy Cabbage]

I parse `$visitors.Description` to tally frequency, by which it is ordered (descending):

- `$descriptions` = [(Betty Butternut, 2); (Adam Aardvark, 1); (Cathy Cabbage, 1); (Daniel Dingo, 1); (Enid Endive, 1)]

I skip Betty Butternut (appears more than once in `$descriptions`), and then check whether the other `$numUnique`=**4** names (Adam Aardvark, Cathy Cabbage, Daniel Dingo, or Enid Endive) appear in `$permanents.Description`.
The number of matches in this example would be `$numMatching`=**2** (corresponding to Cathy Cabbage and Enid Endive);  it doesn't matter if an element of `$descriptions` appears in `$permanents.Description` more than once, that's still just counted as one match.  This is ultimately reported as **2 out of 4** being matched.

*Current code*

Here's a trimmed & anonymised version of my actual code.

```
# Acquire active visitors' data.  
$aGroup = "Visitors"
$sb  = "OU="+ $aGroup +",OU=Active,OU=Acme-Users,DC=acmeauth,DC=acme,DC=com" 
$visitors = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties Description -SearchBase $sb | select Name, Description

# Sort Description parameter for visitors by frequency.  
$descriptions = $visitors | Group-Object {$_.Description} -NoElement | Sort-Object -Property Count -Descending

# Acquire active permanent staff data.  
$aGroup = "Permanent"
$sb  = "OU="+ $aGroup +",OU=Active,OU=Acme-Users,DC=acmeauth,DC=acme,DC=com" 
$permanents = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties Description -SearchBase $sb | select Name, Description

# Iterate through _non-duplicated_ visitor records to find matching permanent staff Description parameters and tally.  
$numUnique = 0
$numMatching = 0

$maxIts = $descriptions.count

for ($index = 0; $index -lt $maxIts; $index++)
{
    $person = $descriptions[$index]
    
    if ($person.count -eq 1) {
        # This person has a unique Description among the (active) visitor cohort.  
        $numUnique++
        if ($permanents.Description -contains $person.name) {
            # This person has a matching Description among the (active) permanent staff cohort.  
            $numMatching++
        }
    }
}
```

In the real application:

- `$visitors.Description` has roughly 450,000 string elements, of which roughly 400,000 are of interest;
- `$permanents.Description` has roughly 20,000 string elements, comprising roughly 19,000 unique values;  and
- `$numMatching` is about 5000.

*Future code*

It turns out that the `Description` field has data entry errors for a scattering of records (*e.g.* "Enid" in the example under *Scenario*), so I am planning to modify the code to instead use a concatenation of `GivenName` and `Surname` parameters (with a space character in between), assigned to arrays as simple strings using `foreach`.

*In a nutshell*

How can I optimise this code?

In particular, how can I get it to run faster?

## Possible improvements

*Tinkering with algorithm*

Implement one of more of the conceptual modifications described under *Alternative concept* and *Possibilities to speed up algorithm*.

*Parallel computation*

Maybe a simple way would be to get the most computationally demanding & repetitive part(s) of the code to run in parallel??
I haven't looked into this in detail, but so far it's a little confusing:  for Powershell 5.1 [a post by js2010 on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56963199) indicates a few alternatives, including "workflows" with a `foreach -parallel` command.  However, [Microsoft says](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-foreach-object-parallel-feature/) "There is currently no parallel support for the `foreach` keyword."  Maybe the latter statement was because the support was removed, so it's not "current" support??

And I don't know for sure whether it's feasible for this application to run in parallel, or (if so) which of the various alternatives would be best (easiest to implement would be my priority, if performance is similar), and whether it'd help much.

*Other ideas*

Anything in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56406847/processing-large-arrays-in-powershell) relevant?  (Excluding the alternative to use something outside of Powershell.)

## System

There is a reasonably powerful workstation that this job can run on.

- Windows 10 Pro for Workstations.
- Powershell 5.1.

I do not want to put any unnecessary load on the AD server.

Comment: Does the `description` attribute contain the _exact_ name, eg. "John Doe", or is it a substring search, eg. "This is the description for John Doe"

Comment: I guess you simply want to [join](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/JoinModule) the list (using a hash table, see: [what's the best way to join two tables into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1848821/1701026)) and get the unique count of a specific property. Something like: `($visitors | Join-Object $permanents -on Description | Select-Object -Unique Description).Count`

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen : in principle `Description` contains the entire name, and nothing else.  As noted, however, in reality there are some data entry errors:  the ones I've noticed involve `Description` containing only a single given name (e.g. "John"). 
 (There's also a separate `DisplayName` attribute that would prefix a title of address, as in "Mr. John Doe" / "Dr. John Doe" / "Rev. John Doe" / ..., which I am not inclined to use, if I can avoid it.)

Comment: @DIV Okay, can you update your post to talk a little more about _the actual task at hand_? You've provided a very comprehensive description (which is great), but it's all in the abstract - knowing _what data_ you're comparing actually helps here :) Why does permanent staff have visitor names in their account descriptions? Can each staff only have 1 guest at a time? etc.

Comment: @iRon : thanks for the suggestion.  I've had a look at the [examples in your code](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/JoinModule/3.8.3/Content/Join.psm1) but I'm still not sure whether that's what I'm trying to do.  Did you have a look at the Concept section, and would your proposal produce the same outcome?  If you're confident it matches my use case, then could you please explain a little more how precisely to implement it and what's happening when `join`ing the lists?

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen : the implication of the sample script is that some people are recorded in AD in _both_ of the  organisational units:  `Permanent` _and_ `Visitors`.  But with different details recorded in each OU (so I cannot match on telephone, address, email, etc.).  It is not about linking different people.  It is about statistics on such multiple records existing for certain individuals.  I know it might sound like an odd statistic, but I'd really rather just leave it as an 'obscure-but-important statistic' than dig into the motivations and statistical theory.  Is that enough to go on?

Comment: @DIV, I am not confident that it completely matches your concept, for that you should add a [mcve] (add two input examples with name/description properties e.g.  `$visitors = ConvertFrom-Csv @'...` and the expected outcome). using to your question

Comment: As aside.. In your code you have `$descriptions = $permanents | Group-Object {...}`, but at that point `$permanents` has not been assigned anything.

Comment: Reading the other comments, apparently you what to compare the description with the names, with would than be something like: `$visitors | Join-Object $permanents -on Description -eq Name` to find your relations.aAyways your description is somewhat confusing an wordy, I really recommend you to create a question based on the [mcve] concept (currently we can only guess what is in your AD description etc.).

Comment: @Theo : thanks, that's a misprint.  Sorry!  The code should say $descriptions = $visitors | Group-Object {...}, which matches the comment above that line.

Comment: @iRon : I wouldn't say that the main purpose is to compare descriptions with names.  (That's more of a side-issue, only to understand whether the main analysis is reliable or not.)  One or the other is to be used to compare records in different AD OU's.  In principle it doesn't matter which is chosen, because both variables would be identical except for data entry errors.  I've added a more practical example under *Scenario*.  Maybe that will clear up some confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specific to your example:

```
$visitor = ConvertFrom-Csv @'
Description
Daniel Dingo
Betty Butternut
Adam Aardvark
Betty Butternut
Cathy Cabbage
Enid Endive
'@

$Permanents = ConvertFrom-Csv @'
Description
Enid
Enid Endive
Betty Butternut
Cathy Cabbage
Fred Flamingo
Cathy Cabbage
'@
```

I am not sure why you remove the duplicate descriptions ***completely*** from the `$Visitors`
(I find this a weird constrain), anyways:

```
$VisitorHash = @{}
foreach ($Description in $Visitor.Description) { $VisitorHash[$Description]++ }
$VisitorDescription = $VisitorHash.GetEnumerator().where{ $_.Value -eq 1 }.Name
```

And not from the `$Permanents` (`Cathy Cabbage`) ???

```
$PermanentsHash = @{}
foreach ($Description in $Permanents.Description) { $PermanentsHash[$Description]++ }
$PermanentsDescription = $PermanentsHash.GetEnumerator().where{ $_.Value -eq 1 }.Name
```

```
$PermanentsDescription = $Permanents.Description
```

Than you might simply use a `where` method or even a `[Linq.Enumerable]::Intersect`
(See also [Comparing two arrays & get the values which are <strike>not</strike> common](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35872835/1701026)):

```
$Intersect = [Linq.Enumerable]::Intersect([string[]]$VisitorDescription, [string[]]$PermanentsDescription)
$Intersect
Cathy Cabbage
Enid Endive
```

You might count the results by forcing the `Linq.Enumerable` to an array (using the [Array subexpression operator `@( )`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#array-subexpression-operator--)):

```
@($Intersect).count
2
```

Comment: Thanks, @iRon.  I am able to reproduce your results with the example given.  I haven't yet tested on the real set to investigate the speed (presumably you're proposing it'd be faster than my simple script).  Yes, the constraints might seem "weird" and inconsistent, but what you wrote was indeed what I want.

Comment: I have one difficulty in implementation.  I can assign `$VisitorDescription.count` from your code to my `$numUnique` (answer = 4).  However, I cannot see how to count the number of matches to assign to my `$numMatching`.  Neither `$matches.count` nor `$matches.length` helps (*they're performed element-by-element*).  `[Enum]::GetValues($matches).Count` (idea from [here](https://powershellmagazine.com/2013/01/17/pstip-get-the-count-of-items-in-an-enumeration/)) didn't run.  ...

Comment: `$matches.Count()` (idea from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count?view=net-7.0)) didn't run.  I found a [post from @Mendelt on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/168922) that might indicate that there's no way to get a count of how many items are in your `[Linq.Enumerable]` thing.  (*Of course, for the illustrative example one can just read them from the screen and count on one's fingers.  But in the real application there will be hundreds of matches.*)

Comment: So what command(s) can be used to get that count?  Or would it be better to use something like `ICollection<T>` or `IList` instead???

Comment: Correction:  *But in the real application there will be **thousands** of matches.*

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I'd tried assigning `$matches = [Linq.Enumerable]::Intersect(...)` in an attempt to get the element count.

Comment: Hi, @iRon.  I get numerous error messages:  `Index operation failed; the array index evaluated to null.`  Although I gave one example of a data entry error, there are also several (~5000) `Visitors` records for which the `Description` field appears to be empty (or `null`) — I guess that is what's causing this.  I suppose this could be dealt with by pre-processing to either *replace* `null` entries with a flag like `"EmptyDescription"` or `"NULL"` (allowing further analysis of those cases). or else *remove* those records.  But either might be slow.  Can you advise of a better approach?

Comment: How about modifying your code to prepend, say, an underscore to every description (including the nulls) `foreach ($Description in $Visitor.Description) { $VisitorHash["_" + $Description]++ }` and then stripping it out in the next line `$VisitorDescription = foreach($nm in $VisitorHash.GetEnumerator().where{ $_.Value -eq 1 }.Name) { $nm.Substring(1, $nm.length-1) }`??

Comment: With the latter modification, your code is *much* faster than my code:  it takes less than a minute (~10 s) in the real application [excluding the separate prior steps to pull the data from the AD server in the first place].  In my code even the sorting looks to take over an hour.   I assume that the numerous repeated calls using the `-contains` operator in my code are also quite slow.

Comment: If it is about preventing a `$Null` key, you might also just quote the key: `$Visitor.Description) { $VisitorHash["$Description"]++ }`

Comment: Adding timings to the script and analysing a smaller subset (14000 visitors; 1600 permanent), my original code takes 53 s (61% of that just for sorting!), whilst your algorithm takes 0.4 s [excluding calls to the AD server].  To avoid data entry errors I've changed from using the `Description` parameter to a 'manual' concatenation of `GivenName` & `Surname`, and the subset timings are similar: respectively 37 s for my code (82% for sorting!), and 0.5 s for your algorithm.  *However*, there's another difference:  my code does **case-insensitive** matching, whilst yours is **case-sensitive**.