# Compare contents of 2 arrays in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have 2 arrays that has folder names with files inside them, I would like to compare just the names of the arrays and not all of its contents, since they are huge < 300000,000 entries or more on both of them.

e.g.: -

```
$array2 = @("Folder1", "Folder2", "Folder3")
$array1 = @("Folder1", "Folder3", "Folder4", "Folder5")
$diff   = @()
```

This is what I have and it's not working, since the arrays are huge. It's been processing for over 10 hrs. with no end in sight. Looks like it's going through the content of each folder.

```
$diff = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $array1 -DifferenceObject $array2 -PassThru
```

Expected result:

```
$diff = @("Folder2" "Folder4" "Folder5")
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: This answer discusses ways to improve performance when comparing two large arrays - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77439335/3156906. It's not an exact duplicate but it should give you some pointers on what you can do (basically, don't use ```Compare-Object```, *do* use hashtables or native dotnet methods)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how big are the collections you want to process this might be a simple way to do it:

```bash
$array1 = @('Folder1', 'Folder3', 'Folder4', 'Folder5')
$array2 = @('Folder1', 'Folder2', 'Folder3')
$result = @(
    $array1.Where{ $_ -notin $array2 }
    $array2.Where{ $_ -notin $array1 })

$result

# Outputs:
#
# Folder4
# Folder5
# Folder2
```

If you need more performance then using hashsets should be beneficial:

```
$hash1 = [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]::new(
    [string[]] ('Folder1', 'Folder3', 'Folder4', 'Folder5'),
    [System.StringComparer]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)

$hash2 = [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]::new(
    [string[]] ('Folder1', 'Folder2', 'Folder3'),
    [System.StringComparer]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)

$result = @(
    $hash1.Where{ -not $hash2.Contains($_) }
    $hash2.Where{ -not $hash1.Contains($_) })

$result
```

Another way to do it using LINQ's `.Intersect` combined with `.Except`:

```
$array1 = @('Folder1', 'Folder3', 'Folder4', 'Folder5')
$array2 = @('Folder1', 'Folder2', 'Folder3')
$combined = [string[]] ($array1 + $array2)

[System.Linq.Enumerable]::Except(
    $combined,
    [System.Linq.Enumerable]::Intersect(
        [string[]] $array1,
        [string[]] $array2))
```

Comment: Thaks so much, looks like it's working in the test i did. I approximately have the same number of items in my sets

Comment: The test I did with about 500k items in one set and about 300k items in another set. It calculated the expected results. I will be running the real test, and I hope it works. Once again appreciate your help.

Comment: Its working fine. Thanks so much! Can you explain the use of casting with the invariantCulture? Thsi is the approach i adopted.

Comment: @Newborn glad it was helpful. The `InvariantCulture` is so that your `HashSet<String>` is case insensitive (it might not be needed for you but something to consider). If you want it to be case-sensitive, which it is by default, you can instantiate it like: `[System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]::new([string[]] ('Folder1', 'Folder2', 'Folder3'))`

Comment: Sounds good. Thanks again.

Comment: @Newborn I had a typo in my code, it is `[System.StringComparer]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` instead of `[System.StringComparer]::InvariantCulture` to make it case insensitive. my bad

Answer (score 1):

You could cast both arrays to HashSet (it'll remove duplicates) and then use set operations on them. SymmetricExceptWith will modify $hs1 to only contain strings in $hs1 or $hs2, but not both.

```
$hs1=[System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]$array1
$hs2=[System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]$array2
$hs1.SymmetricExceptWith($hs2)
[array]$hs1
```

Casting and comparing operations are very fast even for large collections.

Comment: Thanks, AdamL. Looks promising. I am hoping it works. I'll test it and report back with the results.

Comment: I tried testing your script today and i get the following error  :-                               Method invocation failed because [System.Collections.Hashtable] does not contain a method named 'SymmetricExceptWith'.
At C:\test\LogicTest.ps1:28 char:1
+ $OldHash.SymmetricExceptWith($NewHash)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Comment: @Newborn Are you sure you're using HashSet, not HashTable? Post your code